# Angular Material : Display empty option(None) in Mat-Select on initial page load when value is null

Tags: html, angular, angular-material

Need to display the empty (None) option in Material Select element when the item is null.

````
    <mat-label>Status</mat-label>
    <mat-select formControlName="statusId">

        <mat-option>None</mat-option>

        <mat-option *ngFor="let item of statuses" [value]="item.id">
             {{ item.name }}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>```

As seen in above snippet I need to display the "None" option selected by default when the page loads.
````

Answer (score 1):

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-select-demo-bf7ima?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)
So, you can add a empty value to the None option.

```
 <mat-select [formControl]="foodControl" name="food">
      <mat-option value="">None</mat-option>
      <mat-option *ngFor="let food of foods" [value]="food.value">
        {{food.viewValue}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
```

And, in the ts, you can initialize the control with empty value like this
`foodControl = new FormControl('');`

same thing can be done with ngModel as well. (included in the StackBlitz)